# Inserting details of another contact as tokens into an email

Tags: civimail, tokens

I'm trying to set up a template to be sent to one contact. It includes tokens that are specific details of a second contact. How do I specify the contact whose details I am trying to insert through these tokens?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using drupal as your CMS? We have some custom tokens with token data from the organizational record that individuals are related to.

Check it out here, it won't get you all the way as we are using custom fields and relationships not applicable but you may be able to use it as a template of sorts:

https://github.com/elisseck/civi4.6-related-info-token

Answer (score 1):

the second contact is how related to the first? it sounds like some custom tokens. http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+%28and+Custom%29+Tokens

Comment: Yes, we have some of that too (eg details of an alumnus' former school) and we use custom tokens.

Answer (score 0):

We've found another way round the problem by compiling a report and sending that off to the appropriate party! :) Thanks for your advice!